# load external file into div

Tags: jquery, html, load

I am trying to load an external jquery page into a div. I use map tag because my header's image is full of buttons. 
So this is the relevant code

index file:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="loader.js"></script>
..
<area shape="rect";
id="find us";
coords="190,50,265,70";
href="javascript:clicked_on('rectangle');"
..
<div id="text">
//where I want the page to be loaded        
</div>
```

loader file:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("#find us").click(function(){
 // load contact form onclick
 $("#text").load("index.html");
 });
});
```

file to be loaded: index.html

When I click on the icon it does nothing.
But if I include in the loader.js this code at the beginning it loads with the page:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // load index page when the page loads
    $("#text").load("index.html");
```

So the icon doesn't work..

After hours of searching I give up..Hope to find an answer here.
Thanks!

Comment: Shouldn't "us" have a # or . in front of it? or remove the space... or add an underscore.... something needs to be there. From your edit... remove the space in the ID. What you have there is `#find#us` technically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The id attribute can not consist of two words (i.e. have a space in between).

Try `<area shape="rect" id="find_us"...` and `$("#find_us").click(function(){`

Answer (score 2):

try not having spaces in your id. Change it to `find_us` in both places and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

you need to give your area tag a single word for its id:

`id="find_us"` or `id="find-us"`

the all should work ok (remember to call it with that in your click function)